# Java String into Character pointer C

Tags: java, c, string

I have a Java String with below value :

If I print the String then it is printing below :

> Content-Type: application/isup; version=ttc93-tiger; base=ttc93+
>
> ^A^C^B  ^G^C^P^P^B^X^BP
> ^G^C^Q^P^B^Y^CPe^E\236^B--unique-boundary-1

After the we are passing this string in C code and C code is storing this String in Character pointer.Here it is printing

> Content-Type: application/isup; version=ttc93-tiger; base=ttc93+

I mean I am not getting ^A after ward characters.

Any reason why i am not getting above character...some cap ^ is not supporting..something like that..

Comment: And how should we know this string in your C program? Please post some lines of source code! And IMHO it looks like you're doing some HTTP Transfer, some more details would improve the answer.

Comment: Your question lacks so much important detail. How are you transferring the string to your C program? How are you printing it? Show relevant source code etc.

Answer (score 4):

`^A` looks like binary data to me. In Java, a string can contain any character (even 0 bytes) since Java stores the characters and the length of the string. In C, the first 0 byte will terminate the string.

To verify the theory, try to print the String while escaping binary data, for example using `StringEscapeUtils` from commons-lang or writing your own little routine.